# Emberjs - using computed property

Tags: ember.js

This is what I have in a template:

```
{{check-box isChecked=hasPhoneForSecureAlerts visibleLabelLoc=".t.settingscontact.label.phone" class="checkbox-inline narrow" testId="chk-phone"}}
```

This is what I have in controller for this property:

```
hasPhoneForSecureAlerts: Em.computed.bool('securePreferences.phoneLocalNumber'),
```

Let's assume, that originally this property is set to true and check box is checked, If I uncheck check box, this property is set to false and actually does not correspond to state of securePreferences.phoneLocalNumber.

To set it to initial value, when we are leaving this screen without saving, I just use in resetController at corresponding route:

```
controller.set('hasPhoneForSecureAlerts',     controller.get('securePreferences.phoneLocalNumber') !== null);
```

Is this code correct? It actually works fine, but I am finding anywhere in Emberjs documentation something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're code looks like but I think your problem is related to using `Em.computed.bool`. In this situation I would use `Ember.computed.alias` instead and I created a [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sowodapuse/edit?html,js,console,output) to demonstrate that it works. Let me know if you're still having trouble.

EDIT:

Ok, I think I realize now what you're trying to do. As you've noticed, this does work, but I would maybe rethink the way you're going about this simply because a checkbox is designed to be interacted with and what you are doing seems very unnatural. I would instead use a separate variable for your checkbox and make it a property. That way your `property()` function will run anytime the checkbox changes value. If the checkbox changes from checked to unchecked, then you can clear the phone number you have stored. I'm not sure what you would want to happen when the checkbox goes from unchecked to checked though. This is why I feel using a checkbox is a somewhat strange decision. Maybe you could create a minimal jsFiddle to demonstrate what you're intending to happen?

Comment: Actually, I don't have any problems, this code is working. My question is if this is correct code - could this computed property to be used in this way or do I need to do something like that:

Comment: text: "Default",
    textValue: function(key, value) {
        if(arguments.length === 1) {
            return this.get('text');
        } else {
            this.set('text', value);
        }
        return this.get('text');
    }.property('text')

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EW7xD/4/    This actually has code that is working. I agree that it is not natural but it actually works!

Comment: lol ok, I suppose it does work but I guess I would suggest taking another look at the design since the change unchecked->checked would imply strange behavior.

Comment: Actually, check box is interacted with a property of controller which is a computed property. When we are coming to the page through route/controller and etc, it is actually computed depending on what is saved in database. When we uncheck it, property is also set to false and we can save into database using the state of the property. If we are leaving the page without saving, we are resetting property back to where it was before. Somehow it is working very well - not sure what is behind the scene.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but what bothers me is this: if the checkbox is loaded as unchecked, what do you want to happen when it's checked?

Comment: When it is checked, the property is set to true but securePreferences.emailAddress is still false. If I did not click save and just leave this screen, this property is set back to false. if I click Save and leave this screen, it is not set to false as securePreferences.emailAddress is set to true in Save method. This is how it works. The only difference that this computed property is used a little strange. But for me it is just a property and I should be able to set or get.

Comment: Oh, so securePreferences.emailAddress doesn't actually contain an email address?

Comment: It actually contains - the check box will be checked because of state of the following computed property:  hasEmailForSecureAlerts:     Em.computed.bool('securePreferences.emailAddress'), When it is unchecked and saved, 'securePreferences.emailAddress will be set to null and saved into database as null. A little bit confusing - if it is true, securePreferences.emailAddress is set to email address, if it is false, it will be set to null.

Comment: My point though is that if emailAddress=null, then the checkbox is checked by the user, you can't know what email to set emailAddress to. Does that make sense?

Comment: If it is unchecked - there is no email address will be saved. There is a text box that is used to enter email address. This check box just controls if email is required (check box is checked) or not. Pretty strange but this is how it is designed.

Comment: Yeah that is a little strange but ok :)

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I created simple app:

Comment: <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
          {{input type="checkbox" checked=hasPhoneForSecureAlerts}} Email<br>
          <button {{action "testIt" }} >Test It</button>
    </script>

Comment: var App = Ember.Application.create({
});

It works
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController:function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, null);
        controller.set('emailAddress','alex@hotmail.com');
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 hasPhoneForSecureAlerts: Ember.computed.bool('emailAddress'), 
 emailAddress: null,
 testIt: function() {
        window.alert("emailAddress: " + this.get('emailAddress') + 
         "hasPhoneForSecureAlerts: " + this.get('hasPhoneForSecureAlerts'));
    }
});